# Having problems implementing both pinch and 2-touch pan gesture simultaneously

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

What I have is my view controllers view with several subviews. The hierarchy looks something like:

```
[view controller view]
    [container view]
        [view1,view2,view3,view4,view5,etc...]
            [gesture view (full screen)]
```

I'm trying to implement pinch and 2-finger panning, but cannot get them to work simultaneously:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                 initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
pinch.delegate = self;

UIPanGestureRecognizer *pullDownContainerView = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pullingDownContainerView:)];
pullDownContainerView.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
pullDownContainerView.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2;
pullDownContainerView.delegate = self;

[self.touchView addGestureRecognizer:pullingDownContainerView];
[self.touchView addGestureRecognizer:pinch];

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Another strange thing is that `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` isn't being called (I have implemented the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol).
They do work individually. I've read something about using a scroll view where pan and pinch are readily available or something. So I'd need to replace the container view's `UIView` with a `UIScrollView`

Would like some guidance.

**Update:**

Did a quick clean and build and now it's working!

Comment: What is pullViewDown in your code?? Is it a typo??